# MYSQL SELECT QUERY where column is the same

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to query a table in my database, basically I need to select the driver_id from the table where the team_id is the same as the users driver id, stored in a variable $user_driver_one. So pretty much selecting the other driver with the same team_id.

```
column driver_id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

  column team_id 3 3 2 2 1 1 4 4 5 5
```

So the user could have $user_driver_one = 4, so I need to select in a query the driver_id = 3, as driver_id 3 has the same team_id.

I am having problems with this, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious what is the relation between driver_id an team_id. Why do you want people that have the same id as their team ? Looks like a code smell.

Comment: basically the drivers all belong to a team, this is formula one. and the user selects 3 drivers, so in the query, I need to be able to select the teammate of the driver the user has selected.

Comment: I updated my answer after you edited your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you escape the parameter

```
$user_driver_one = (int) $user_driver_one;
```

MySQL:

```
"SELECT `driver_id` 
 FROM `table` 
 WHERE `team_id` = (
     SELECT `team_id`
     FROM `table`
     WHERE `driver_id` = '$user_driver_one'
     LIMIT 1
    )
 AND `driver_id` != '$user_driver_one'";
```

Comment: No problem! Take an hour or two to learn some Subquery and Join basics and you will feel so much more confident with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT driver_id FROM T1 WHERE team_id = driver_id AND team_id = @user_driver_one
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna use PHP it would look like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT driver_id FROM tablename WHERE team_id = '$user_driver_one'");
```

Of course, some sanitation before doing a query would be smart, especially if you're assigning the $user_driver_one variable from a user input.

Answer (score 0):

```
select driver_id from yourtablename where team_id in (select team_id from yourtablename where driver_id=4)and driver_id!=4
```

You can use $user_driver_one in place of 4